# Custom controls SharePoint webpart Property Panel

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can you please give me an idea how to render custom controls in property panel of webpart? My Requirement is to add a dropdown list,TextBox and a button to add selected items in the textbox in property panel. I am able to create TextBox,DropDown List and checkbox in property panel but found no way to create buttons and other controls.

Regards,
Sharmila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use a tool part for the same sample code is available at the following link [Tool Part](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/11/29/how-to-custom-web-part-properties-toolpart.aspx)